# How to detect free memory slots in Solaris 9 using software?

Tags: solaris

I would like to know if there is any command which would tell me if there are any free memory slots in the server.
The servers I would be looking would be Solaris 9 OS/Sparc.

Comment: Can you tell us in more detail what you're trying to do? Do you want to use software which will tell you which slots to use or list number of available slots or type of RAM used or what else? Right now it's difficult to determine what's being asked here.

Comment: I am in need of additional memory to run more application on the box, i would like know beforehand if the slots are available, so that a request could be raised with hardware team for increasing the RAM. Hope that explains.

Comment: I edited the question to make your needs a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `/usr/platform/$(uname -i)/sbin/prtdiag -v` to get an idea about what is installed in your box and what memory slots are free.